# $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)}$ for multivariable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$${\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (1,1)}} \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-2}{\left | x-1 \right |+\left | y-1 \right |}$$
The book provided the suggestion of substituting $x-1=v$ and $y-1=u$ although I did not find that to help. I am getting the value of $0$ as the limit but I am not confident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=1$, and $x \rightarrow 1^+$,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} \frac{x^2-1}{|x-1|}= \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} (x+1)=2$$

Let $y=1$, and $x \rightarrow 1^-$,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} \frac{x^2-1}{|x-1|}= -\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} (x+1)=-2$$

You should be able to conclude something about existence of such limit.